# get timestamp in perl

Tags: perl

my yesterday date is 201103116

I want to take starttime timestamp and endtime time stamp for yesterday in perl.

Comment: If you just want a unix timestamp, use `time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Perl-core way would be:

```
my ( $y, $m, $d ) = unpack 'A4 A2 A2', $date;
my $start_ts      = POSIX::mktime( 0, 0, 0, $d,     $m - 1, $y - 1900 );
my $end_ts        = POSIX::mktime( 0, 0, 0, $d + 1, $m - 1, $y - 1900 );
```

see [**`POSIX`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX)

And with `mktime` it's perfectly okay to just add negatives to values. So if you need to have 23:59:59 as your end date as suggested in the comments, you can just fix it up with this:

```
my $end_ts = POSIX::mktime( -1, 0, 0, $d + 1, $m - 1, $y - 1900 );
```

(Although, I would just like to note that the excluded endpoint is not an unknown case in programming.)

Comment: Technically `$end_ts` is the first timestamp of the next day. Easily fixed by subtracting 1 though, if necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Using [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
use DateTime;

my $start = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local')->subtract(days => 1)
                ->set(hour => 0, minute => 0, second => 0);
my $end   = $start->clone()->add(days => 1, seconds => -1);

print $start,       " - ",$end,"\n";            # 2011-03-15T00:00:00 - 2011-03-15T23:59:59
print $start->epoch," - ",$end->epoch,"\n";     # 1300147200 - 1300233599
```

Comment: That will not necessarily get today's date where you are. For that, change `->now` to `->now(time_zone => 'local')`.

Answer (score 2):

I did not understand your question. However, have a look at [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime).

Comment: in client system, does not installed the Datetime and posix not working, and also there is no possibility to use install the datetime module, so is it possible, guide with combined of linux commands and perl snippet, somthing line date "%YM%D" +%s

Comment: @Bharanikumar - POSIX is core module included with every perl5 installation

Comment: but i tried with mktime(), but not worked, if my server, then i can check but its client machine cant able to question